# Node.js Redis Connection Pooling

Tags: node.js, redis, connection-pooling

When using [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) Node.js module with Redis, should I just use one connection as Redis is single thread process or shall I create a pool of connections to improve performance?

Comment: A doubt, why do you need connection pool

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just use a single connection. Both Node and Redis are *effectively* single thread. I don't think you'll gain anything by having multiple connections. I asked a similar question before starting to develop with Redis and it seems that one client/one application is pretty effective pattern.

Highlighting an important note from the comments on this question. (Thanks to
oskarth & stockholmux)

> **For long running processes like servers, it is okay to use a single long lived connection.**

Comment: If I'm running a long-lived node web server, should I just create a client and let it live, without ever running `.end` or `.quit` on it?

Comment: @oskarth Yep. I've done this in production for years now. The only reason to call `.quit` is if you want to gracefully shut down your process for some reason (`.end` is rather brutal, I avoid it).

Comment: If you use `PUBLISH`/`SUBSCRIBE` or `WATCH` then you'll need a separate connection(s).

Comment: Do I still need pooling If I only use :
var batch = redis_client.batch();
    batch.set(key, value);
    batch.publish(key, value);
    batch.exec();

Comment: @MuhammadHassan No. You don't need pooling. `batch` is a language construct and you publishing with `publish` doesn't block the client.

Comment: This answer can be seconded with this page. [Node.js with Redis](https://redislabs.com/lp/node-js-redis/). An Excerpt from the page *Since Node.js and Redis are both effectively single threaded there is no need to use multiple client instances or any pooling mechanism save for a few exceptions;*

Comment: @MasterChief to be fair, I wrote that page you're referring to.

Comment: @stockholmux, Didn't knew that sir, well written article. Thoroughly enjoyed it. Cheers.

Answer (score 11):

There is a use case for pooling multiple connections, actually: blocking commands like BRPOP and SUBSCRIBE.

Comment: VPhantom, that's useful information, but please include a complete answer to the OP's question.

Comment: I haven't yet used [generic-pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generic-pool) with Redis, so I can't formulate a more complete answer.  I merely clicked on "add a comment" but it appears that because I am new, what I typed ended up being a full answer.  That was not my intent. :(

Comment: In deed, blocking commands will block your connection so if you try to do a command such as XADD while you have a blocking XREAD or XREADGROUP your add will be blocked until the reads unblock...