# Redis, a new connection every time vs keep an open connection

Tags: node.js, redis

I have a Node microservice listening to a queue and I persist some messages into a Redis (every 4-5 seconds), and I do not know which is the best option.

Should I keep an open connection to my Redis or it is better to open and close connections every time the database is used?

Comment: Have a pool of persistent connections, yes. Opening connection for each command is huge performance penalty.

Comment: As @SergioTulentsev said the best way to have a connection pool of redis connection. However, this link can help you to use a connection pool. https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-connection-pool. `a redis client connection pool . A node.js connection pool for Redis.` A helpful information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383467/redis-connection-pools-node-js

Answer (score 3):

As @SergioTulentsev explained, it is better to use a single connection.

If you are using `ioredis`, you are covered because even if your client is disconencted, `ioredis` will try to reconnect for you and also, it will have an in-memory command qeueu that it will fill up until the client is connected again and then, `ioredis` will send all those command again.

#### More Info

https://github.com/luin/ioredis#offline-queue

> When a command can't be processed by Redis (being sent before the ready event), by default, it's added to the offline queue and will be executed when it can be processed. You can disable this feature by setting the enableOfflineQueue option to false:
>
> const redis = new Redis({ enableOfflineQueue: false });