# Redis get and set race condition question

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I have been reviewing every topic I can on this and cant seem to get the answer I'm looking for so here is the questions.

(using node.js)

I have a chat server that is clustered. When a user joins a room put their data in redis

```
redis.get(room, function(err, results){
if ( results !== null)
{

var myData {socket:socket.id,name:nickName};
results.push(myData)
myData = JSON.stringidy(myData);
redist.set(room,myData)
}
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it but my goal is to keep a simple list of people in the room.

However if a user leaves the room I perform a similar task as above, get grab the redis key, serialize and pop the user out of the array and then stringify and put it back in.

My question is, will I run into race conditions if say a user leaves and joins at the same time. So the scenario would be something like

Users joins the room and the key is updated with their information however at the same time another users leaves the room and updates the key, essentially user leaving could potentially have the older set from the join so the joinroom may not be the most current?

I have read that redis is atomic for set and get but then I also see mentions of race conditions as well so I'm confused at how this would work?

Will I run into issues or does redis block until the operation is done and moves to the next call? I'm also not convinced my approach is the best way to go about it because I have to stringify etc to remove items from the list and what not but I have not seen a better option?

Anyhow help or guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have one issue to fix before considering the race condition issue!

Your web chat server is clustered so you need to tell `Socket.IO` where to keep(in-memory) the socket ids otherwise a socket client in instance A won't communicate to a socket client in instance B. Each instance of your chat server runs an isolated socket server which make communication impossible between them.

To solve this, use `Socket.IO` Redis adapter: [socket.io-redis](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis)

Please note that `socket.io-redis` adapter uses `PUBLISH/SUBSCRIBE` so you should make a new Redis connection to [avoid blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37005795/3632172) instead of passing your existing Redis client.

Simply pass your Redis info to the adapter like this:

```js
io.adapter(redisAdapter({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

**Back to the race condition topic.**

To avoid the race condition there, you must call `get` and `set` **ATOMICALLY**. To achieve that, you should use Lua scripting with the `EVAL` command to ensure that concurrent clients will modify rooms data sequentially.