# Why does node-redis not use Redis connection pools?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I'm currently working on a high-throughput application, and was looking for some advice regarding the idea of connection pooling when connecting to Redis from Node.js using node-redis.

When you run a benchmark using `redis-benchmark`, the [documentation](https://redis.io/docs/reference/optimization/benchmarks) says it defaults to using 50 clients. However, when you use popular modules like node-redis, it only opens one. The differences in performance between multiple connections and a single connection are not trivial, and don't appear to be offset by pipelining.

A quick sample using just the `redis-benchmark` tool on a m5a.2xlarge shows the following results.

With a single client:

```
redis-benchmark -q -P 16 -c 1
PING_INLINE: 179211.45 requests per second, p50=0.079 msec
PING_MBULK: 192307.70 requests per second, p50=0.071 msec
SET: 171232.88 requests per second, p50=0.087 msec
GET: 179533.22 requests per second, p50=0.079 msec
INCR: 178890.88 requests per second, p50=0.079 msec
LPUSH: 166944.92 requests per second, p50=0.087 msec
RPUSH: 171821.30 requests per second, p50=0.087 msec
LPOP: 162601.62 requests per second, p50=0.087 msec
RPOP: 165562.92 requests per second, p50=0.087 msec
SADD: 176366.86 requests per second, p50=0.079 msec
HSET: 168350.17 requests per second, p50=0.087 msec
SPOP: 185873.61 requests per second, p50=0.079 msec
ZADD: 165562.92 requests per second, p50=0.087 msec
ZPOPMIN: 186567.16 requests per second, p50=0.079 msec
```

With multiple clients:

```
redis-benchmark -q -P 16
PING_INLINE: 847457.62 requests per second, p50=0.839 msec
PING_MBULK: 1041666.69 requests per second, p50=0.663 msec
SET: 694444.50 requests per second, p50=1.071 msec
GET: 840336.12 requests per second, p50=0.863 msec
INCR: 800000.00 requests per second, p50=0.911 msec
LPUSH: 625000.00 requests per second, p50=1.215 msec
RPUSH: 675675.69 requests per second, p50=1.111 msec
LPOP: 568181.81 requests per second, p50=1.335 msec
RPOP: 606060.56 requests per second, p50=1.263 msec
SADD: 781249.94 requests per second, p50=0.943 msec
HSET: 621118.00 requests per second, p50=1.215 msec
SPOP: 917431.19 requests per second, p50=0.783 msec
ZADD: 591716.00 requests per second, p50=1.295 msec
ZPOPMIN: 854700.88 requests per second, p50=0.847 msec
```

So in general, it looks like you get 4-5x the throughput by using multiple clients - something which, on the surface, seems like an easy win in terms of squeezing extra performance out of your hardware.

With that in mind, I guess what I'm wondering is, if multiple connections increases throughput so much, why do things like node-redis not appear to support it by default? Or am I just missing something!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js Redis Connection Pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976270/node-js-redis-connection-pooling)

Comment: @LeibaleEidelman Thanks for the link. I had read it, but I'm still not sure it really explains the logic behind it. As Redis is also single threaded, but opening multiple connections helps it go faster, why would opening multiple connections from Node not also improve performance?

Comment: @v_flashpont https://github.com/redis/node-redis/issues/226#issuecomment-8573407

Comment: @LeibaleEidelman Thanks for the link. I'd found that discussion in my search too, but it seems to mostly be people asking the same question as me. If it makes sense in certain high throughput situations to open multiple connections, why does node-redis not allow for it? Or is there a good argument against it?